# How to derive this problem with soft-thresholding method?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, optimization, lasso, signal-processing

The problem is defined as 
$$
\min_{x} \Bigg\{ a{\|x\|}^2+\frac{b}{2}{\|x-c\|}^2 \Bigg\}
$$
where $x\in R^{n \times 1}, c \in R^{n \times 1}$ and $a,b$ are scalars.
Equations 2.5 to 2.8 of [this paper](http://www.caam.rice.edu/~optimization/L1/GroupSparsity/group110419.pdf) say this could be solved by soft-thresholding, and the $\arg \min$ is
$$
x ^*=\frac{c}{\|c\|_2}\max \Bigg\{ {\|c\|}_2-\frac{a}{b}, 0 \Bigg\}
$$
Could anyone provide some references on how to derivative this solution, please?

My derivation is as follows:
$$
ax^Tx+\frac{b}{2}(x^Tx-2x^Tc+c^Tc)=\left(a+\frac{b}{2}\right)x^Tx-bx^Tc+\frac{b}{2}c^Tc
$$
Then, the minimum is at the point that gradient is zero, i.e.
$$
(2a+b)x-bc=0
$$
then, $x=\frac{b}{2a+b}c$.

What's wrong with my derivation?

Comment: @VincentGuillemot, could you please read the paper above, about the equations 2.5 to 2.8. Does I misunderstand the procedure? If it was a $l1$ norm, then I know how to derive the soft-thresholding. But, in the equation 2.6, it's a $l2$ norm. Thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly, it is a sum of $\ell_2$ norms: an $\ell_2$ norm is applied to each subvector of $x$ corresponding to a group. If the groups contain each one variable and if each variable is contained in a group (and the weights are all equal to one), then $||x||_{w,1,2} = ||x||_1$.

Comment: My previous comment applies to Eq. 2.5. In Eq. 2.6 there is indeed an $\ell_2$ norm, which is very different from what you wrote : in your expression, the norm is squared. It is not in Eq. 2.6. In order to solve this problem with an ("un-squared") $\ell_2$ norm, you will need the expression of its sub-gradient. It should then be very similar to the same demonstration with an $\ell_1$ norm.

Comment: @VincentGuillemot, thank you for so detail explanation. I think my wrong point is that I just consider the $z=\sum_{i=1}^{s}z_{g_i}$ and $\min_{z}=\min \sum_{i=1}^{s} z_{g_i}$, then it is separable. Then it is formally presented as above in this post. Maybe this is misunderstood. In addition, could you please suggest some references about solving the problem with "un-squared" $l_2$ norm using sub-gradient methods? Does the "squared hinge loss Support Vector Machine" belong to the "un-squared" $l_2$ loss? Thank you!